# Extracting elements from whole set of list in r

Tags: r, list, igraph

The code below is my R script. I want to fetch the $r[[1]] and $r1 from my r script's resultant list: `loop_results`.  Below is a sample of how only a portion of the first element of `loop_results` looks.  I want a list only showing the sequence of shortest paths like 1 and 1 2 and a list that only contains vertex sequence like A and A B.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]]$r
[[1]][[1]]$r[[1]]
[1] 1


[[1]][[1]]$r1
Vertex sequence:
[1] "A"


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]]$r
[[1]][[2]]$r[[1]]
[1] 1 2


[[1]][[2]]$r1
Vertex sequence:
[1] "A" "B"
```

Here is my R script

```
library(igraph)
  g <- graph.ring(5) # the graph
  V(g)$name <- LETTERS[1:5] # Vertex names
  # Define functions:
  val=function(g,i,j) { r=get.shortest.paths(g, i,j ,mode = "out"); return(r) } 
  val_all=function(r) { r1 <- V(g)[r$vpath[[1]]]; return(r1) }

  loop_results <- list()
  for (i in 1:5) {
    loop_results[i] <- list(NULL)
    for(j in 1:5) { 

      r=val(g ,i, j)
      print(r[[1]]) 
      r1 = val_all(r)
      print(r1)
      loop_results[[i]][[j]] <- list(r=r[[1]], r1=r1)
    }
  }
  loop_results
```

I get the below output from `dput(loop_results)`:

```
  list(list(structure(list(r = list(1), r1 = structure(1, 
  class ="igraph.vs", env = <environment>)), .Names = c("r", 
  "r1")), structure(list(r = list(c(1, 2)), 
   r1 = structure(c(1, 2), 
   class = "igraph.vs", env = <environment>)), .Names = c("r", "r1")),
   structure(list(r = list(c(1, 2, 3)), r1 = structure(c(1, 2, 3), 
   class = "igraph.vs", env = <environment>)), .Names = c("r", "r1")),
    structure(list(r = list(c(1, 5, 4)), r1 = structure(c(1, 5, 4)       class = "igraph.vs",env = <environment>)), 
    .Names = c("r", "r1")), structure(list(r = list(c(1, 5)), r1 =      structure(c(1, 5),class = "igraph.vs", env = <environment>)), .Names = c("r", "r1")))
```

in this form for each of the remaining 4 letters also.  R in get.shortest.path function will only return the sequence of shortest paths as numbers.  If we are having vertices with Strings then we for printing out the vertex sequence names with the result of shortest paths I used val_all function in my r script.

My main goal is to find the list which contains the shortest path sequences with intermediate nodes. Like if in my example I want to find the shortest path between Nodes "A" and "C" the result would be A B C. Then, I just want to print the intermediate node which is "B" not "A" and "C", which are the nodes from and to which I am finding shortest path. For this purpose, I am thinking of using setdiff() function in r, and for this function I need to pass a list, which is why I wanted the list which I previously mentioned.

Comment: i checked out my script it is producing the output. And i want the result by extracting the resultant list elements of $r[[1]] above before R script i shown.That list before my r script i shown is half list. I want result of $r[[1]] only from the output list.

Comment: Hi frank, My desired output from the half list i shown is [1] 1 , [1]1 2 like this sequence. I want to fetch only those portion from that list which is named in my half list as [[1]][[1]]$r1 then [[1]][[2]]$r1 this part only i want to fetch from the list.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you post the `dput(yourlist)` for the sample data that you used?

Comment: @Frank sorry for the inconvenience. Yes I want list into two separate lists of r data and r1 data. Yes I want the result in that form only.

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune  I am not getting you..

Comment: Pierre is asking you to enter `dput(loop_results)` into R, then copy the output, and paste it in the question.  We (I suspect it's not just me) are not getting the same output as you post...  `r` is the output of `get.shortest.path`, which is going to output letters, not numbers, because you named the vertices using letters.  My output also doesn't contain the words "Vertex sequence:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the existing list into two lists based on whether the data is associated with `r` or `r1`, you can use  a nested `lapply` call to accomplish this:

`r`:

```
lapply(seq_along(loop_results), 
    function(x) lapply(seq_along(loop_results[[x]]), 
         function(y) loop_results[[x]][[y]][["r"]]))
```

`r1`:

```
lapply(seq_along(loop_results), 
    function(x) lapply(seq_along(loop_results[[x]]), 
        function(y) loop_results[[x]][[y]][["r1"]]))
```